# How can I display the names of employees under the same company on my Django index page?

Tags: python, django

Django display value in list of same row name

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField()
    #companyname=models.OneToOneField(Insert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employeename= models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```

this is my index page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bd0f.png)
urls.py

```
 path('', views.companies_view),
```

what i want is

```
Apple   [None, Jessica, Matthew, Anthony]
```

instead of

```
apple jessica
apple matthew
apple Anthony
```

Comment: How do you link the employee to a user?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem there's no authentication here. These are the only two models.

Comment: @user92600781: how are you currently rendering the tables?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem     companies = Company.objects.all() in views.py {% for company in companies %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ company.name }} <a href="{% url 'api:form_view' company.id %}">(Add Employee)</a></td>
        <td>{{ company.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ company.employeename}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %} in html

Comment: please [edit] the question. The modeling looks wrong. An `Employee` should have a fk to `Company`, not in reverse, otherwise you make one company *per* employee...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modeling looks wrong. If a `Company` can have multiple `Employee`s, you make a `ForeignKey` from `Employee` to its `Company` not the other way around. Otherwise you will need to create a `Company` per `Employee`, which makes the database unmaintanable.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employees'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

A `ForeignKey` thus acts as a *many-to-one* relation, not a <s>*one-to-many*</s> relation.

Then in the view we can fetch the `Company`s and the corresponding `Employee`s:

```
def index(request):
    companies = Company.objects.prefetch_related('employees')
    return render(
        request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'companies': companies}
    )
```

and render with:

```
<table>
    {% for company in companies %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ company.name }} <a href="{% url 'api:form_view' company.id %}">(Add Employee)</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ company.id }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                {% for employee in company.employees.all %}
                <li>{{ employee }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```